# How to execute script in active tab without using broad host permissions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome browser extension, and I'd like to execute a script using `chrome.tabs.executeScript();` whenever the the active tab is updated without requesting broad host permissions (`"<all_urls>"`). My code doesn't work unless I request broad host permissions. What do I do?

I've already tried using a content script, but that requires broad host permissions.

**manifest.json permissions**

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
 ],
```

**background.js**

```
// get active tab
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, tabs => {
    // run when tab is updated
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
        // execute script in active tab (tabs[0].tabId)
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].tabId, {code: "alert();"});
    });
});
```

I think using `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` requires host permissions, not just `activeTab` permissions, even if run only on the active tab.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or a work-around for this?

Comment: This won't work because 1) `activeTab` requires an explicit user gesture (see the documentation) and 2) the code is using the wrong sequence of calls anyway: it gets the tab at the moment the background script runs which may happen at the wrong time, and then it listens to changes in all tabs but updates the one that was active in the beginning - it just doesn't make any sense, but even if the correct sequence is used it won't help due to point 1. You can use the [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) which aren't checked by the web store *currently*.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, your advice is very helpful. I'm very new to all this. I tried using `<all_urls>` as an optional permission, but it didn't work. I added it as a required permission and it works now. Is it possible to execute a script on the active tab when it's updated without request broad host permissions?

Comment: See the examples in the documentation I've linked. Just adding an optional permission isn't enough.

Comment: @wOxxOm Requesting permissions like that won't work well for the purpose I have intended. Is there any way to execute a script only on the currently active tab whenever it is updated?

Comment: Requesting is performed only once, why is that a problem? Are you trying to make a malware? Anyway there are no other methods as that would be a huge security hole.